# Memory management issues when passing items between arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I'm attempting to move a group of strings between three different places by calling this function getNextRandomItem.  This works the first time I call it, but then I get an access error the second time.  Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

New Items:binNew (NSMutable Array) -> Current Item (NS String) -> Old Items:binOld (NSMutable Array)

```
-(NSString *) getNextRandomItem {
    if (binNew.count > 0){
        if (currentItem) {
            [binUsed addObject:currentItem];
        }

        int r = floor(arc4random() % binNew.count);
        currentItem = [binNew objectAtIndex:r];
        [binNew removeObjectAtIndex:r];
        return currentItem;
    }
    return @"No more items!";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to retain r when it is removed from the array. Now you remove it and set its pointer to currentItem. The retain count should become 0 so that probably will cause the error. You have two options.

1) Add a property in your interface:

```
@property (retain) NSString *currentItem;
```

and add this to your implementation

```
@synthesize currentItem;
```

then use

```
self.currentItem = ...
```

instead of

```
currentItem = ...
```

2) Use correct memory management. See altered code:

```
-(NSString *) getNextRandomItem {
    if (binNew.count > 0){
        if (currentItem) {
            [binUsed addObject:currentItem];
            [currentItem release]; //See here
            currentItem = nil; //See here
        }

        int r = floor(arc4random() % binNew.count);
        currentItem = [[binNew objectAtIndex:r] retain]; //See here
        [binNew removeObjectAtIndex:r];
        return currentItem;
    } else {
       [currentItem release];
       currentItem = nil;
    }
    return @"No more items!";
}
```

Note currently you never set your currentItem to nil. You should do that.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
currentItem = [binNew objectAtIndex:r];
```

should  be

```
currentItem = [[[binNew objectAtIndex:r] retain] autorelease];
```

When you remove object from container with `[binNew removeObjectAtIndex:r]`, it receives `release` message and without `retain`-ing it, you get an invalid pointer (because it points to released object).

Comment: You're wrong, retain and then autorelease just discard each other (I mean the object would be autoreleased anyway)

Comment: @Max: Actually he's right. The object would not be autoreleased; objectAtIndex: returns a non-owning reference. That CAN be done with autorelease pools, but that's not the only way to do it. In this case, it just returns a pointer to the object inside the array. If you want it to exist after it is removed from the array, you MUST retain it before removing it.

Comment: Max is right. This will cause the release to happen in the end of the runloop instead of directly. You want a retain, so the object will never deallocate.

Comment: Not exactly. autorelease does not release object immediately and we need to return valid object from getNextRandomItem.

Comment: Release message would be sent as many times as autorelease is called: eg: [[[NSData data] autorelease] autorelease]  would crash cause release message would be sent 3 times

Comment: @Max: no it wont (try it). `autorelease` adds object to autorelease pool, it doesn't release it, the pool does. Besides, `currentItem` will be retained by addObject: (assuming it still points to the same object).

Comment: i don't say autorelease releases. it adds to autorelease pool. just try [[NSData data] autorelease] - it crashes

Comment: Nope it doesn't. Why don't you try your code yourself and post a stack trace here? -)

Comment: @tundrabot, it does release the object. You just dont know when it releases it. In the main thread, it will be when you application stops, but when you use threads, well... Then your f'ed. Your solution will work, but is not correct. When you say your object will not release, you object will live forever (until your release pool is drained, and that is the end of the main). You better retain it and release it at the correct moment. That is a) you will set the currentString to another object, or you want to set currentString to nil.

Comment: @tundrabot are you kidding? Just paste it in your applicationDidFinishLaunching and start

Comment: @Mats Stijlaart: on the main thread, pool is drained at the end of each run loop iteration, not at the end of main(). There was nothing about threads in the question, that's the whole different story.

Comment: @tundrabot Mat is right. Pool is drained at the and of the main. But objects are autoreleased at each iteration of thread's run loop.

Comment: @tundrabot: Well, there is nothing said about threads, your right. But let me give you a methaphore: Do you wash a new car the same way you wash an old car? Or you use dirty water for the old car?... Its the same with programming. Do it well and don't leave bad smells, otherwise just don't do it.

Comment: @Max, @Mats Stijlaart: from NSAutoreleasePool Class Reference: The Application Kit creates an autorelease pool on the main thread at the beginning of every cycle of the event loop, and drains it at the end, thereby releasing any autoreleased objects generated while processing an event. Why don't you guys learn to ride bikes first -)

Comment: @tundrabot look at your main.m file: do you see Autorelease pool there? and where is it released (drained)...at the end? Other pools are created and deleted implicitly by run loop. Do you still say that [[NSData data] autorelease] doesn't crash?

Comment: @tundabot, let me quote you: 'at the beginning of every cycle of the event loop, and drains it at the end', this means EVERY event, so when you release an object one to often with an autorelease, your screwed. If you do not believe me (and Max), then just agree to disagree. Maybe you will not get errors when working with one thread, but with more threads it will not.

Comment: I probably shouldn't jump into the fray -- I'm very much a newbie here, and I don't know anything about memory managment.  But I did try this solution first in my code and it continued to crash every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSString *) getNextRandomItem {
    if (binNew.count > 0){
        if (currentItem) {
            [binUsed addObject: currentItem];
            [currentItem release]; //here
            currentItem = nil;//not really necessary
        }

        int r = floor(arc4random() % binNew.count);
        currentItem = [[binNew objectAtIndex:r] retain]; //and here
        [binNew removeObjectAtIndex:r];
        return currentItem;
    }
    return @"No more items!";
}
```

Comment: Hee max, you say currentItem = nil;, not really necessary. But you will have to set it to nil sometime (last object). Do it in the else. See my post.

Comment: In this case it's not necessary cause array size is always const. But yes, it's better to add that.